# Lightning page not working anymore with new updates in salesforce community

Tags: salesforce, lightning, sfdc

I am re-writing and extending the our Lightning product which was created 4 months back. But I am getting some issue in code which used to work fine in previous version. I haven't changed anything from last working version.

In navigation menu I added a custom community page named favorite article. 
Now this page is displaying error message "invalid page".